# Change the font color of a numeric value C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

trying to change the font color of a numeric value,but getting error:Input string was not a correct format.

Eg code:

```
DataTable dt = PDSData.getPDSBndl(bndlId, 'N');
string qty = "<font color='red'><i><b>" + dt.Rows[i]["qty"].ToString() + "</b></i></font>";
dt.Rows[i]["qty"] =Convert.ToInt32(qty); //@ this line Getting error.
```

I have tried converting string to int,but no hopes.

Comment: Please don't use `<font color="">`, it is obsolete even in HTML4. Use `<span style="">` instead.

Comment: how u show this ? via gridview or Div ?

Comment: where u want to show that numeric value in label or in any other control?

Answer (score 2):

You can not parse something like `bgfbgb56ngfngn` to int. The dataTable itselfs only contains data, no formatting information.

You need to change the view (ASP.NET WebForm or razor view, whatever you use) to handle the display.

Comment: so if i want to change the color of 'qty' variable ,how can i do that.Actually am implementing the same to other variable,its working fine,but not working for qty variable.

Comment: You can not change the color of a variable. You can render the variable in a place where style information is proveded. To answer "How can I do this" you have proveded not enough information. You need to show at least how you are rendering your view

Comment: Binding the datatable to a repeater control
rpt.DataSource = dt;
                rpt.DataBind();

Comment: Inside the view you will have something like `<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"qty") %>`. Outside of it you can place the font color html. Like so: `<font color='red'><i><b><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"qty") %></b></i></font>`

Answer (score 1):

As you mention in answer of suscha by comment 
"Binding the datatable to a repeater control rpt.DataSource = dt; rpt.DataBind(); – user1676709"
You are using in repeater then you can do like this..

```
 <span style="font-weight:bold;font-style:italic;color:#ff0000;"><%# Eval("qty") %></span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of problems:

1. Your variable qty will never be an integer as you are adding HTML tags to it.
2. You do not apply font settings on to variables. You do that on the UI element you are using.

Answer (score 0):

The string **qty** is holding a sting value like `'<font color='red'><i><b>" + dt.Rows[i]["qty"].ToString() + "</b></i></font>'` & you are trying to cast into int32 which is not valid. If **qty** is holding string value like "9" or "10", it will convert it but in your case it will give error. Use Int32.TryParse to check whether the string is correct & in out parameter you will get the converted value if tryparse returns true.

Comment: In database qty is of type integer.and some reason i need to change the color of the qty.so am appending font tag to string and trying to place it in datatable

Comment: Insert the integer itself in database, while rendering or showing on screen you show it with desired font & color or hold an extra string field in database to store the font color of that integer.

Answer (score 0):

if you want it show in a gridview, manage this in design.
if you have conditions to set color, then manage in itemdatabound event of grid view.